# Stackoverflow for Teams Data Download broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I cannot seem to download the Stackoverflow for Teams private team content with the `Download data` button on the page `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<team_name_here>/admin/billing/account`. I tried this today and yesterday.

[image: The download button]

[image: Something bad happened]

What needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report! The fix is on production now.